# Groovy: No such property: data for class: groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder$RequestConfigDelegate

Tags: grails, groovy

I have a class that uses the [HTTPBuilder library for Groovy](http://groovy.codehaus.org/modules/http-builder/). I got this error:

```
Class
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException
Message
No such property: 
data for class: groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder$RequestConfigDelegate
```

What does it mean?

Here is the code:

```
def myService = new HTTPBuilder("http://example.com")
        myService.request(POST) {
            uri.path = "/myservice/"
            requestContentType = JSON
            body = [ parameter1 : value1, parameter2: value2]
            headers = [From: "header:myheader"]

            response.success = { resp, data ->
                if(!data.completed) {
                    render(contentType: "text/json") { success = false }
                }
                render(contentType: "text/json") { success = data.completed }
            }

            response.failure = { resp ->
                if(!data.completed) {
                    render(contentType: "text/json") { success = false }
                }
                render(contentType: "text/json") { success = data.completed }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see, you are not declaring the `data` in the `response.failure` closure but trying to refer it. Try the following block:

```
response.failure = { resp, data ->
    if(!data.completed) {
        render(contentType: "text/json") { success = false }
    }
    render(contentType: "text/json") { success = data.completed }
}
```